# How to measure number of installs on versions of an iOS app

Tags: google-play, app-store, app-store-connect, developer-console

I have an app published on Apple's app store via iTunes Connect. I also have the same app published on Google's Play store.

Both platforms are on their 3rd version and I need to measure the number of installs of each version. Google have made this easy - in the developer console click 'Statistics' then 'App Version':

[image]

However, I'm struggling to find a similar report in iTunes Connect.

Is there a way to achieve this with iOS apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get similar (but not the same nice overview!) information for apps using iOS8+ via Apple's own App Analytics without integrating any 3rd party SDK.

Go to https://analytics.itunes.apple.com/ > Your App > Metrics

Then choose from the "Usage" metrics on the left either "Installations" or "Sessions" (1) and plot them by "App Versions" (2). Please note that usage metrics only included "opt-in" data. (I'd also adjust the time interval if needed)

You can get your opt-in rate by clicking on the little "?" in the top right next to "About App Analytics" in almost every view.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That is similar to what I'd like to see. It doesn't seem to include upgrades unfortunately, just installations. It's also not clear if the figures are for number of installs happening on a given date, or the number of devices with the app installed on a given date. I suspect the former. Many thanks though - this is progress!

Comment: These numbers are all defined in the docs. I also wrote a short intro to App Analytics over on Medium: https://medium.com/transporter-library/apple-app-analytics-101-93f399b41ff4

Comment: Thanks - found the definitions page. Nice article too.